# Using SELECT to evaluate a function?

Tags: sql, function

This is homework assignment question from my Database Theory Class. The book seems not to relate with the possible answers any suggestions would be appreciated.

8. What is the general syntax for using SELECT to evaluate a function?
   (a) `SELECT [(parameter_list)] FROM function`  
   (b) `SELECT function WHERE (parameter_list)`
   (c) `SELECT function [(parameter_list)]`
   (d) `SELECT function [(parameter_list)] WHERE database_name`

My Answer: C

Comment: Thank you for telling right away this is a homework and it is good that you put already effort to think about it. I'd say you are right.

Comment: The answer depends on the DBMS. None of the answers would comply with standard SQL as a `FROM` is always required there. But the closest are probably c and d

Comment: Without SQL context - usual function syntax is `function(parameters)`, thereby a) and b) do not look right anyway. In SQL context `where` clause is not used to specify database(s), thereby d) seems wrong also. Remains c); for MS SQL server it is correct, for some other DBMS it may need additional clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am new to the Overflow community and I am still getting use to this awesome environment. I do want to use this forum properly and welcome any constructive advice that well help me to use the Overflow correctly. Ron Mccool

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is `C`, because `parameter_list` must have a function, and `WHERE` must have `FROM`.